# Delete a Linux signal handler in C

Tags: c, linux, event-handling, signals

I use:

```
signal(SIGINT, CtrlHandler);
```

To add handler of `SIGINT` event. But how can i delete this handler?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is what you do:

```
signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
```

That resets the signal handler back to whatever the default behavior was for that signal (including the default disposition if it hasn't been set). In the case of SIGINT, it's aborting your process without a core dump.

[The manual for `signal`](http://man.he.net/?topic=signal&section=2) explains why this works:

> `signal(signum, handler)` sets the disposition of the signal `signum` to `handler`, which is either `SIG_IGN`, `SIG_DFL`, or the address of a  programmer-defined  function (a "signal handler"). ... If the disposition is set to `SIG_DFL`, then the default action associated with the signal occurs.

You can also find this information using the `man` command. If you type `man signal` on the command line and read through, you should see it.

This is very specific to the case in which you've replaced the system default signal handler. In some situations, what you want is to simply restore whatever handler was there in the first place. If you look at the definition of `signal` it looks like this:

```
sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);
```

So, it returns a `sighandler_t`. The `sighandler_t` that it returns represents the previous 'disposition' of the signal. So, another way to handle this is to simply save the value it returns and then restore that value when you want to remove your own handler.

Comment: @jameshfisher - Thank you for the edit. Sometimes I get frustrated with people who don't read the manual. :-)

Comment: What if an application installed its own signal handler, and then a library temporarily installed one? In this case, the library needs to restore the former handler, and not the default one.

Comment: @jww - I addressed this issue. Is that what you were looking for?